# Pivot table and manual correction in excel

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, from a data source which contains false values  for a specific date.

Some people in my department provided with the correction of the agregated numbers.

Do I have a way to insert a manual correction *just* for this cell point or is the **only** way to copy by value etc....?

Answer (score 0):

I believe correcting the source data is your best option.  Of course the best thing would be if they could give you the corrected individual data points.

If you can't get that, then I think you need to add a helper column to the source data that will contain corrected numbers that you calculate based on the ratio between the incorrect aggregate and the correct one:

[image]

In this example, to the right I've calculated the ratio between the incorrect and correct aggregates.  Column C is the new helper column.  It contains a formula with an IF statement that checks the date.  IF it's the date with the problem it multiplies each individual amount by the Correction Ratio in G2.  You can then change your pivot table to use Column B instead of Column C.

It's important to to note that Column C now contains incorrect data by row.  So again, stating the obvious, the best thing would be if they give you the detail data!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that correcting the source is the *only* way to fix it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I generally agree, although the OP mentioned copying the pivot table as values and then hand-correcting.  You can also create a table that refers to the pivot table and do the corrections there with cumbersome formulas that you'll surely forget to update at some point.  Having used all three, fixing the source is the best.  So, given that, what did you think of my implementation?

Comment: An additional builtin annotation mechanism would have been welcomed. but I guess you are right ino saying it does not exists. I ended reprogramming an 'unpivot' operation  -> correct value-> pivot ....

Comment: @nicolas I don't know what you mean by "builtin annotation mechanism" or "reprogramming an 'unpivot' operation".

Comment: Well annotation of computed values is basically what i am looking. it would have been useful natively in Excel. Unpivot is an operation, called 'melt' in R if you are more familiar with that.

Comment: I am familiar with unpivoting/melting and have even answered a question about it here on SO.  I'm curious though how you can unpivot to detailed data that doesn't exist.